# Equality on the definition of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

It is hard for me to see that for any B and for any $A \in \mathscr G$
$$E[I_{B}E[I_AY|\mathscr G ]] = E[I_{B}I_AE[Y|\mathscr G ]] $$

Could someone help me to see it

Note: I would like to understand why this equality hold, I know that since $1_A$ is $\mathscr G$ measurable I could bring it outside the conditional expectation.

Comment: It is unclear to me. You have already known the proof of the equality. So, what is your problem?

Comment: @FengShao what I want is like proving the validity of this step. Seeing the equality with the integral and understand why the two integral give the same result

Comment: your $A,B$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable sets, right?

Comment: So in short, you are just asking why $E[I_A Y \mid \mathscr{G}] = I_A E[Y \mid \mathscr{G}]$?  You say you "know" this is true, and any textbook that discusses conditional expectation should have a proof....?

Comment: @NateEldredge yes exactly. I'm following probability essentials of Jacod and Protter and this step is left at the reader.

Comment: @CelineHarumi yes, right.

Comment: The answer below comes directly from the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space; $\mathcal{G}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$; and $Z$ a random variable on $\Omega$ so that $Z\in L^1$. By definition, you might know that $E[Z\mid \mathcal{G}]$ is a  random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{G})$ (also in $L^1$) satisfying
$$E[1_AE[Z\mid\mathcal{G}]]=E[1_AZ]$$
since $A$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Take the random variable $Z=Y1_B$ on $\Omega$ (with finite expectation), and you are done.

Ok, see that

$$E[1_AE[1_BY\mid\mathcal{G}]]=E[1_A1_BY]=E[1_A1_BE[Y\mid \mathcal{G}]].$$

Comment: Y shouldn't be $\mathscr F$ measurable? otherwise is pointless define a conditional expectation of a r.v. on his sigma algebra. therefore also Y$1_B$  should be $\mathscr F$ measurable

Comment: Given the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, when I say that $Z$ is a random variable on $\Omega$, it is implicitly understood that $Z$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. So, yes.

Comment: Ok, my doubt come from what you write before correcting it